# How to center 2 EditTexts one on the right of the other in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I want to achieve the following:

[image]

This is all centered on the bottom below other widgets. It is all in a RelativeLayout. The blue EditText (edittexts) has to be clickable and other color. How do I align those two editTexts on the bottom, one next to the other?

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/parent_relative"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_user_login"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/circlered"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDisplayPrijava"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Prijava z MojAvto računom"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textViewLoginEmail"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textViewDisplayPrijava"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textViewDisplayPrijava"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/textViewDisplayPrijava"
        android:hint="E-poštni naslov"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="20dp"/>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextGeslo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textViewLoginEmail"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textViewLoginEmail"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/textViewLoginEmail"
        android:hint="Geslo"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPozabljenoGeslo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/textViewDisplayPrijava"
        android:layout_below="@id/editTextGeslo"
        android:text="Pozabljeno geslo"
        android:onClick="forgotPassword"
        android:clickable="true"/>



    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textViewPozabljenoGeslo"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textViewDisplayPrijava"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/textViewDisplayPrijava"
        android:text="PRIJAVA"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewNimatePrijave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="EditText1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textViewNimatePrijave"
        android:text="EditText2"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please post your xml code!

Comment: Have you tried the `layout_alignBaseline` attribute?

Comment: @appersiano Added the code

Comment: @Karakuri I've tried now that you mentioned it, but I wasn't able to center them correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use nested view.

Put it inside a container view, like (LinearLayout or RelativeLayout) and allign it to the center.

Here is the code example:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:id="@+id/text_view_first"
                      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                      android:text="There are 2"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text_view_first"
                      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                      android:id="@+id/edit_text_second"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text="editText"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

if you need to support versions of API greater than API 16, then instead of `android:layout_alignParentLeft` it will be preferable to use `android:layout_alignParentStart`. Here the link to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#layout_alignParentStart).

[Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) you can find the guide, provided by Google, how to use RelativeLayout to it's full power.

Comment: @mythic, glad to help you.